# How many eggs are there in the basket?

Tags: problem-solving

> There is a basket of eggs. The remainder is
>
> - $1$ when we put the eggs in groups of $2$.
> - $2$ when we put the eggs in groups of $3$.
> - $3$ when we put the eggs in groups of $4$.
> - $4$ and $5$, respectively, when we put the eggs in groups of $5$ and $6$.
>
> How many eggs are there in the basket?

Comment: I see you've made at least 5 questions on this MSE, but you accepted only one of the answers given to you. You should accept your favorite answer.

Comment: @GitGud perhaps they were not suitable answers?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck If that's the case, my comment was unwarranted.

Comment: @GitGud also, I have some pretty infamous questions with ten plus answers. No particular answer stood out, so I chose to not accept specifically because I wanted it to be clear that all the answers were equally sufficient, and equally engaging Tldr - not all questions can necessarily choose one answer to accept due to their nice diversity.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I didn't want to fully explain the situation, but since you took the time to dissect this, let me do it too. Firstly, I take back what I said about my comment being unwarranted because I said the OP should accept their favorite answer - this is pretty obvious that they should do on the assumption that there is favorite answer, otherwise my comment talks about something which doesn't exist, it's meaningless. (Continues).

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Secondly, naturally one doesn't always do things right the first time around, I've improved my standard comment for this sort of situation, something along the lines of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309267/quadratic-equation#comment669554_309267) which is more informative than imperative, then the OP can decide for themselves. **TLDR:** Old comment, I've since changed my ways of taking this sort of issue on.

Comment: @GitGud that is a good improvement. I just didn't want the op to inadvertently feel pressured into accepting, as there are many instances in which people accept an answer out of obligation and then never receive a proper answer because they get ignored due to acceptance. Anyway, I did not mean to bother you. I received an answer here during review and happened to notice your post. I did not know it was an old post. Oops. Sorry about that. :p

Answer (score 4):

Hint. If you have $n$ eggs, then $n+1$ is divisible by $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, and $6$.

Answer (score 1):

59 eggs.

LCM of 2,3,4,5 and 6 is 60 which is divisible by 1,2,3,4,5 and 6.  so if 1

is subtracted the required result is obtained which is 59. so at least

59 eggs is the answer.

Comment: Good answer but please add more detail as to why subtracting 1 provides the appropriate number. Maybe point out that it is 59 + 60K as well, where k is any integer. - from first post review

Comment: @TheGreatDuck $k$ cannot be any integer, as $60 k + 59$ must be nonnegative (it's the number of eggs).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo That kinda goes without saying... We are obviously talking about positive numbers here.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is over three years old, why not just give the solution? In [Haskell](http://tryhaskell.org/):

```
λ take 10 $ filter (\n->(rem n 2==1) && (rem n 3==2) && (rem n 4==3) && (rem n 5==4) && (rem n 6==5)) [1..]
[59,119,179,239,299,359,419,479,539,599]
```

Hence, the number of eggs is in the set $\{ 60 m - 1 \mid m \in \mathbb N^+ \}$. What is so special about $60$?